# Haskell - Create list by adding element from one list only if its equal to element at same index in another list

Tags: haskell

Here is the problem I want to solve:

The two lists `[1,2,3,4] [2,2,3,4]` is to become `[2,3,4]` , because elements at index position zero are not equal. So elements are compared for equality with respect to their index. You can assume equal length lists as input.

So I created a function that solved this with recursion:

```
oneHelper :: (Eq t) => [t] -> [t] -> [t]
oneHelper [] [] = [] 
oneHelper (x:xs) (y:ys) = if x == y then [x] ++ oneHelper xs ys
                          else oneHelper xs ys
```

Then I tried to solve it with list comprehension like this:

```
test a b = [x | x <- a, y <- b, x == y]
```

which just gives me `[2,2,3,4]` with example input above used. I feel like there is a neat way of solving this with a list comprehension, or just a more neat way than the solution I came up with in general, but I am struggling to reach that solution. Does anyone see something better than what I did for the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the two generators, you will iterate over all possible combinations of the elements in the first list (`a`) and second list (`b`).

You probably want to use [**`zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip) here where we iterate over the two lists *concurrently*:

```
test a b = [x | (x, y) <- zip a b, x == y]
```

Comment: "if you use the two generators, you will iterate over all possible combinations..", Thanks for the enlightenment.